# Mocha / Sinon Mock 3rd Party Library Function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Currently testing out the Intercom API, and when once you include the library you can send custom events as such.

```
Intercom('trackEvent', 'myevent');
```

Intercom API is available globally.

My question is how to best mock an event like this in Unit Test ?

```
Intercom('trackEvent', 'myevent');
```

If I call this within a function and run the test I get the following error

```
"Intercom is not defined"
```

So I tried something like this, would that be the correct approach

1. In my Global test set up file `global.Intercom = () => {}`
2. or in the Unit Test itself something like `sinon.stub(window, 'Intercom').returns({});`